# How to change an NSImageVeiw object to its alternate image in Objective C applescript?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, applescript

Using Xcode I am trying to change an image object to another image. I am using ObjC Applescript. I have an IB Outlet "testImage : missing value" and using the following code: `tell testImage to setImage("sample.png")`

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have added the code that I have tryied already @vadian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change an NSImageView object to its alternate image in Objective C applescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965369/how-do-i-change-an-nsimageview-object-to-its-alternate-image-in-objective-c-appl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set image to current application's NSImage's `imageNamed_("sample.png")`
testImage's `setImage_(image)`