# How do I change an NSImageView object to its alternate image in Objective C applescript?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, applescript

Using Xcode I am trying to change an image object to another image. I am using ObjC Applescript. I have an IB Outlet `testImage : missing value` and using `tell testImage to setImage("sample.png")` to change the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
set image to current application's NSImage's imageNamed_("sample.png")
testImage's setImage_(image)
```